# Cannot reinstall or run Stringr package

Tags: r, ubuntu, stringr, failed-installation

I recently upgrade ubuntu from 18.04 to 20.04, so this is probably related...

My code requires me to have the stringr package and to use tidyverse. When I try to run `require(stringr)` and `library(tidyverse)` I receive these errors,

```
> require(stringr) # String manipulation
Loading required package: stringr
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘stringr’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/home/elrodlab/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/stringi/libs/stringi.so':
  libicui18n.so.60: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
> library(tidyverse)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/home/elrodlab/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/stringi/libs/stringi.so':
  libicui18n.so.60: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I've tried reinstalling stringr using `install.packages("stringr")` but then get

```
Installing package into ‘/home/elrodlab/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/stringr_1.4.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 135777 bytes (132 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 132 KB

* installing *source* package ‘stringr’ ...
** package ‘stringr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
mv: cannot move '/home/elrodlab/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/stringr' to '/home/elrodlab/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/00LOCK-stringr/stringr': Permission denied
ERROR: cannot remove earlier installation, is it in use?
* removing ‘/home/elrodlab/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/stringr’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘stringr’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmptRvgMm/downloaded_packages’
```

Although it seems as if Stringr is good to go and all there, when I attempt to use `require(stringr)` I end up getting this error

> `Loading required package: stringr Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘stringr’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):  unable to load shared object '/home/elrodlab/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/stringi/libs/stringi.so': libicui18n.so.60: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Any idea on how to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

The second message seems to indicate that *stringr* was actually successfully installed. Try running again

```
require(stringr)
```

Comment: Hm, thanks for the response. I just edited my question to reflect what happens when I attempt that. It leads to an error, which is why I'm essentially trying to reinstall Stringr.